# How to make an angular form read only and make it editable with edit button?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to make the entire Angular form read only and then editable when clicking edit?

Comment: you can disable all the form fields untill you click the button

Comment: look at @Sunil D. approach which would be cool to implement

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NT3c7XRS6Plh3nEYZWx8?p=preview   For starters I want to enable one box when pressing button.  I have a can edit function set to false and the field disabled set to true.

Comment: take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/NT3c7XRS6Plh3nEYZWx8?p=preview

Comment: What did you change?  The edit button doesn't make the input editable.

Comment: plunkr was not updated take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/Ys1UDakHRxRNItb06fPW?p=preview

Comment: Cool.  That works. Thanks.  Another quick question.  I started learning xeditable and think it's awesome.  However, is there a way to edit an input field without xeditable kicking off a brand new edit field.  Let me create an example and send you the link to make things clearer.

Comment: should I add an answer?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/jF4pi0Kn5AfWhmfHOPJR?p=preview    Here's an example.  With angular I know there's two way binding so this may seem redundant.  I want to be able to click edit, start typing, then save without the help of the extra xeditable box.  Or, since the input is already editable just get rid of the edit and have save?

Answer (score 27):

You can individually disable all the form elements as suggested in the current answer/comments, or you can wrap all of your form elements in a `<fieldset>` [(more info)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) tag and then enable/disable everything in one step:

```
<form>
  <fieldset ng-disabled="myBooleanValue">
    <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Before using a fieldset I want to use one field.  
 
plnkr.co/edit/NT3c7XRS6Plh3nEYZWx8?p=preview   Edit isn't working

Comment: Wow superb... :-)

Comment: i'm using template driven forms in ng9 and setting the fieldset to disabled appears to work for inputs, checkboxes, but not mat-select. Has anyone else solved this nuance?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `ng-disabled="someBoolean"` to your form elements, and set `someBoolean` to `true` when you click a button.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it, i create a css class using pointer-events, pointer-events: none prevents click, state or cursor options so:

```
.formdisabled
{
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Then in view i use ng-class on form like this:

```
<form ng-class="{'formdisabled': !disableForm}">
 <input type="text" ng-model="name">
</form>
```

In view add button to play with the disableForm:

```
<md-button ng-click="disableForm = !disableForm">Show/Hide Form</md-button>
```

Change opacity value if needed.