# How to disable entire form including ion-checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a form that includes several ion-checkboxes and I'd like to make it read only.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059993/150342) I added a boolean to a fieldset. It works for selects and textboxes. But ion checkboxes, while they look disabled, still fire the click event and toggle their state

```
<form>
  <fieldset ng-disabled="myBooleanValue">
    <!-- selects and textboxes are all disabled as you'd expect-->
    <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="va in q.ValidAnswers | orderBy:'SortOrder'"
                  ng-click="vm.setAnswer(q.ID, va.AnswerID)"
                  ng-checked="vm.isChecked(currentAnswers, va.AnswerID)">
        {{va.Text}}
    </ion-checkbox>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ng-disabled` to the `ion-checkbox`:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-disabled="myBooleanValue" 
              ng-repeat="va in q.ValidAnswers | orderBy:'SortOrder'" 
              ng-click="vm.setAnswer(q.ID, va.AnswerID)" 
              ng-checked="vm.isChecked(currentAnswers, va.AnswerID)"> {{va.Text}}
</ion-checkbox>
```

Add `ng-click="myBooleanValue || ..."`:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-disabled="myBooleanValue" 
              ng-repeat="va in q.ValidAnswers | orderBy:'SortOrder'" 
              ng-click="myBooleanValue || vm.setAnswer(q.ID, va.AnswerID)"
              ng-checked="vm.isChecked(currentAnswers, va.AnswerID)">
   {{va.Text}}
</ion-checkbox>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1oub4yhg/2/

Reference: [ng-click still fires](https://baudehlo.com/2014/02/24/angular-js-ng-click-still-fires-when-div-is-ngdisabled/)

Comment: I had found a solution by adding `ng-disabled` to the `ion-checkbox` and then using `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`. That meant that I had to add `ng-model` too. But I like this solution better. +1